# Changing Legend Symbology to include a 'Sum' field using QGIS 3.16.3 Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, legend, zonal-statistics

I currently have a vector layer that contains intensity polygons and are colour co-ordinated depending on the level of intensity. Within this 'Intensity' file, there are two columns `Intensity` and `Affected_P`. The file currents shows the intensity in the legend for the symbology but I would like to include the sum statistic created - `Affected_P` too the legend as well. So, for example, the legend with the intensity then the `Affected_P` field in brackets - 2.4 (60,000). Ideally, done within the Python Console.

The fields/columns look like this. Currently, there are multiple `Affected_P` values for one intensity. I am not too sure if it would add all the values automatically when adding to the specific intensity legend you want or that you would have to add in a piece of code to this.

[image]

The legend looks like this currently but I would like the `Affected_P` column shown next to the intensity number for each colour
[image]

Invalid syntax error when I try to add the code to python, under where I have changed the symbology.

```
#Change symbology
default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('Spectral') #Spectral color ramp
color_ramp.invert()

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Intensity')[0]
field_index = layer.fields().lookupField('Intensity')
unique_values = list(layer.uniqueValues(field_index))
categories = []
for value in sorted(unique_values):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
    categories.append(category)
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer( "intensity" || ' - ' || sum("affected_p","intensity"), categories) 
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the legend-item in the print composer, or about the display in the layers tree?

Comment: Display in the layers tree. If it is unavailable to do it within the layers tree, then the legend-item in the print composer is okay! Thanks

Comment: Using QGIS 3.16 you may edit entries in the legend-item using expressions. I don't know, whether you may edit the entries in the layer tree.

Comment: Ah okay I see thank you. I will see if anyone answers as to whether to edit the entries in the layer tree. Would you know how to use a code to edit the entry in the legend-item? Thanks

Comment: Please place code in the Question body as text. This makes it legible, searchable, and reproducible without tedious copying.

Comment: @Vince Sorry my mistake. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adapt the code you are using to categorize based on the expression suggested by @JGH, you actually need to create the list of unique values and `QgsRendererCategory` list based on the expression.

Please try the code below, adapted (and 'Pythonicized') from the logic in the `addCategories()` method of `QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererWidget` class which starts at line 760 of [qgscategorizedsymbolrendererwidget.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/44466a3322cc49069477ff692453569dc57a8386/src/gui/symbology/qgscategorizedsymbolrendererwidget.cpp).

```py
default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('Spectral') #Spectral color ramp
color_ramp.invert()

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Intensity')[0]

exp_string = '"Intensity" || \' -\' || \' (\' || sum("Affected_P", "Intensity") || \')\''
unique_values = []
exp = QgsExpression(exp_string)
#print(exp.isValid())
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope())
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.atlasScope(None))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer))
exp.prepare(context)
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    context.setFeature(feat)
    val = exp.evaluate(context)
    if val not in unique_values:
        unique_values.append(val)
#print(unique_values)

categories = []
for value in sorted(unique_values):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
    categories.append(category)
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(exp_string, categories) 
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.setOpacity(0.55)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of categorizing the data by `intensity`, you can categorized it by a concatenation of `intensity` and `affected_p`

The expression would be similar to  `"intensity" || ' - ' || sum("affected_p","intensity")`

The example below use the average instead of the sum:
[image]

Comment: When I use the python console, I currently use this code but it says that the || are invalid syntax. I will add a screenshot above.

Comment: make this expression (all of it, including the `'`, `"` and `||`) a string in your python code

Comment: I have used the expression: renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(str("intensity" || ' - ' || sum("affected_p","intensity")), categories) but it still comes up with 'Invalid Syntax'...

Comment: no, you must create a string that contains ALL of the given information.. something like `"\"intensity\" || ' - ' || sum(\"affected_p\",\"intensity\""` (note the surrounding double quotes and, inside the expression, the escaping of the double quotes that should be retained)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run the script now it works but only when I go on to the Intensity file symbology and re-classify the data. Do you know why this is the case? Do I need to write a code like 'renderer.update...'? Thanks